# How to I implement a "ShutdownFinished-Event" to detect when the dispatcher shuts down?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to implement a **shutdownFinished** event in my WPF C# code, to detect when the dispatcher shuts down.

Therefore I would like to use an event which is activated when ***'Dispatcher.HasShutdownFinished'*** is true.

It would be great if there is an example - thanks!

Comment: You can probably use [ShutdownFinished event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.shutdownfinished(v=vs.110).aspx) that is already implemented.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu: that should be probably an answer rather than a comment.